# Why does Salesforce standard API sends records in batches, even though no batch size specified?

Tags: rest-api

In our Salesforce implementation, we are striving to use standard APIs' as far as possible. One of our list APIs' has around 1200+ objects, yet it is returning only 250 in response, along with a `nextRecordsUrl` field that loads the next 250 objects and so on ...

How can I make the API return all 1200+ records in a single call? We are not specifying any batch size, yet this standard API is returning only 250 objects in one call. As I understand it, this is some internal paging done by Salesforce to optimize the response size/speed latency.

We really need to get all 1200+ objects in a single API call, and using only standard Salesforce APIs' (i.e. without writing custom code in Apex).

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] so you know how best to get an answer to your question. Please [edit] it to include the client code that is invoking the API, or at least what REST API URL you are using, so we can better understand your use case. Also, have you read the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386264&type=1)?

Answer (score 2):

There are two modes of operation in Salesforce: synchronous and asynchronous. A synchronous request needs to be responsive as possible so that all subscribers have fair access to the service they are paying for. Asynchronous requests have higher limits, with the understanding that these requests will take longer.

If you want to avoid pagination, use one of the asynchronous APIs. For example, the metadata API can deliver thousands of objects in a single API call, and the Bulk API can return thousands of records in a single API call. You have a choice when working with Salesforce: you can get small and fast responses, or large and slow responses.

However, many of the APIs do allow you to specify a batch size, typically up to 2000 items, in a single response. Check out the documentation for the specific API you're using to see if the option is available.

Even if you specify a batch size for those APIs, be aware that if the response is really large, Salesforce may still require pagination. This is to ensure that subscribers can get timely responses to the billions of API calls Salesforce handles every day.